# why are service's functions added to controller's scope not accessible?

Tags: angularjs

This makes no sense to me; but doesn’t surprise me too much it would work this way.

I wanted to add a function to a click on an HTML page.

my HTML page is assigned ListsCtrl as controller in the .state for that .html page.

I created a service called Favorites and then added this service to the Controller.

I then want to access my function as an ng-click on the html page. This all seems to make sense; but doesn’t work.

The only way I seem to be able to access the functions in my service is to add a wrapper function in the ctrl and explicitly call the function with the service name prepended.

So in ctrl I have this:

```
.controller('ListsCtrl', function($scope, $location, Placemarks, $ionicViewService, $ionicListDelegate, Favorites) {
  $scope.hello1 = function () {
    Favorites.hello3();
  };
```

And in html file then I obviously am calling hello1; even though common sense would suggest I could simply call hello3 directly.

Am I missing some other line somewhere that should add Favorites (service) to the .controller?

Comment: *"I created a service called Favorites and then added this service to the Controller."* Show how you add service to controller that it doesn't work. Post non working code.

Comment: You are trying to fire a function of a service with ng-click and skip the creation of a function in scope?

Comment: Please post the code for your service.

Comment: attach fiddle please.

Comment: Did you remember about use injector? You have to use $inject method on your controller before passing services as controller parameter.
Try ListsCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$location', 'Placemarks', '$ionicViewService', '$ionicListDelegate', 'Favorites']; Show us more code.

Comment: what I understand: You want to be able to fire a service function as following ng-click="service.hello3()" without creating a wrapper of that function in the scope.. is that what you are asking ? If that's the case angular ngCLick directive does an scope.$apply(scope, handler).. that resolve the expression you put with in the scope, because of that you need the wrapper.